# IP Multicast + UDP: Should I receive data for all groups?

Tags: sockets, delphi, multicast, keil

What is the right behavior of IP Multicast over UDP?

Imagine yourself following scenario:

1. We try to speak to IP protocol over UDP.
2. We open an UDP socket with specific port (for example 60001)
3. Then we join the socket to some multicast group (for example 239.192.0.1)
4. We open another UDP socket with port 60002
5. Then we join the socket to other multicast group (for example 239.192.0.2)

When it is done in Windows, with Winsock, each socket becomes data only when both conditions are met:

- UDP port matches
- and multicast group matches.

Here is some Delphi code for that:

```
procedure Connect();
var err: Integer;
    wData: WsaData;
    reuse: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(wData, SizeOf(wData), 0);
  err := WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), wData);
  if err = SOCKET_ERROR then Exit;

  _fd := socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if _fd = INVALID_SOCKET then Exit;

  reuse := 1;
  if (setsockopt(_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, Pointer(@reuse), SizeOf(reuse)) < 0) then Exit;

  FillChar(_addr, sizeof(_addr), 0);
  _addr.sin_family := AF_INET;
  if (_listeningInterface = '0.0.0.0') or not _isIpAddress(_listeningInterface) then
    _addr.sin_addr.s_addr := htonl(INADDR_ANY)
  else
    _addr.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(_listeningInterface));
  _addr.sin_port := htons(_port);

  if (bind(_fd, _addr, sizeof(_addr)) < 0) then Exit;

  if _isMulticast() then begin
    _mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(_multicastGroup));
    if (_listeningInterface = '0.0.0.0') or not _isIpAddress(_listeningInterface) then
      _mreq.imr_interface.s_addr := htonl(INADDR_ANY)
    else
      _mreq.imr_interface.s_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(_listeningInterface));
    // Joinig multicast group here. Note the _fd variable usage here.
    if (setsockopt(_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, @_mreq, sizeof(_mreq)) < 0) then Exit;
  end;
end;
```

When we try to do it from Keil library for microcontrollers, there is no function like `setsockopt` for that. There is `igmp_join` function that doesn't accept socket variable, but multicast group only.

As a result, we cannot specify correspondence of an UDP port and multicast group, and each UDP socket becomes data for all groups we joined to.

Which of two approaches is the right one: Keil's or Windows' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both behaviors are correct.

Which UDP packets you receive on which socket is beyond the scope of the definition of IPv4 multicast.

The expectation that you only receive the traffic you joined the group for is often violated. Also, all operating systems implement this differently. Linux and Windows behave differently, and the small IP stacks in microcontrollers usually have even simpler behavior.

The baseline, the worst case you can expect is: You will receive random UDP packets on your UDP socket, even from groups you did *not* join. But it is usually not that bad in practice. Just as a guideline when thinking about it. The reason is: The OS may delay membership drops. The local routers *will* delay membership drops. The local routers will contain bugs.

You need to deal with receiving unexpected UDP packets anyway, since anyone in your network can forge UDP packets and send them to your socket in somebody elses name. Also anybody else can forge IGMP packets and "join you" to any multicast groups.

This means: In practice you always need to do application-level filtering and silently ignore unexpected UDP packets. On most IP stacks there is a (non-trivial) option to determine the *destination address* of a received UDP packet. This is most useful for splitting out the traffic for multiple multicast groups.

And since you now know the behavior of your IP stack you can for example save some memory and just use a single UDP socket to receive all UDP traffic and de-multiplex it on the application side. It depends also a bit on your application of course.

But yes, I understand your disappointment about IP multicast being so under-defined. I feel with you! :-)